# docker-compose up cannot build Gatsby app npm problem

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, npm, gatsby

I have just started using Docker. I have a very simple project structure based on nestjs as a backend and Gatsby as a frontend. I am using docker-compose to run both backend and client. Both backend and client have a Dockerfile. Where nestjs works without any problem and runs on port `:3000` but Gatsby throws some errors while building.

`Dockerfile` for nestjs:

```
FROM node:12-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/backend

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

`Dockerfile` for Gatsby:

```
FROM node:12-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/client

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  backend:
    image: docker-nestjs-backend
    build: ./backend
    command: npm start
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/usr/src/app/backend
      - /usr/src/app/backend/node_modules
    ports:
      - 3002:3000

  client:
    image: docker-gatsby-client
    build: ./client
    command: npm start
    volumes:
      - ./client:/usr/src/app/client
      - /usr/src/app/client/node_modules
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - backend
```

and here is what I get back on Terminal:

```
Creating network "cwr_default" with the default driver
Building backend
Step 1/7 : FROM node:12-alpine
12-alpine: Pulling from library/node
c9b1b535fdd9: Pull complete
750cdd924064: Pull complete
2078ab7cf9df: Pull complete
02f523899354: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:e280e51eaa6e626e4df58a5c1f141e453807c30596179330992c55a0bf4114ca
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:12-alpine
 ---> afd897e3184b
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app/backend
 ---> Running in b07d7945e145
Removing intermediate container b07d7945e145
 ---> 2b9a35fe4b56
Step 3/7 : COPY package*.json ./
 ---> 9c20c9b6c88a
Step 4/7 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 4dac91dfce96

> @nestjs/core@6.11.6 postinstall /usr/src/app/backend/node_modules/@nestjs/core
> opencollective || exit 0

                           Thanks for installing nest 
                 Please consider donating to our open collective
                        to help us maintain this package.

                           Number of contributors: 406
                              Number of backers: 289
                              Annual budget: $56,036
                             Current balance: $1,623

             Become a partner: https://opencollective.com/nest/donate

npm WARN backend@0.0.1 No description
npm WARN backend@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

added 1093 packages from 696 contributors and audited 910291 packages in 29.688s

32 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

Removing intermediate container 4dac91dfce96
 ---> 21f3869db087
Step 5/7 : COPY . .
 ---> c61ad09009c6
Step 6/7 : EXPOSE 3000
 ---> Running in b81c69060fc8
Removing intermediate container b81c69060fc8
 ---> 114c5ed9f29b
Step 7/7 : CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
 ---> Running in 8d84e41f0fe8
Removing intermediate container 8d84e41f0fe8
 ---> 7785df15b2c9
Successfully built 7785df15b2c9
Successfully tagged docker-nestjs-backend:latest
WARNING: Image for service backend was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Building client
Step 1/7 : FROM node:12-alpine
 ---> afd897e3184b
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app/client
 ---> Running in 5e2d91bc4031
Removing intermediate container 5e2d91bc4031
 ---> 64d6238fa83a
Step 3/7 : COPY package*.json ./
 ---> 1a7b60b8e0bd
Step 4/7 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in a927c5229081

> sharp@0.23.4 install /usr/src/app/client/node_modules/sharp
> (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)

info sharp Downloading https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.8.1/libvips-8.8.1-linuxmusl-x64.tar.gz

> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall /usr/src/app/client/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
> https://opencollective.com/core-js 
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock 

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)


> core-js-pure@3.6.4 postinstall /usr/src/app/client/node_modules/core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
> https://opencollective.com/core-js 
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock 

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)


> gatsby-telemetry@1.1.47 postinstall /usr/src/app/client/node_modules/gatsby-telemetry
> node src/postinstall.js || true

╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║                                                                        ║
║   Gatsby collects anonymous usage analytics                            ║
║   to help improve Gatsby for all users.                                ║
║                                                                        ║
║   If you'd like to opt-out, you can use `gatsby telemetry --disable`   ║
║   To learn more, checkout https://gatsby.dev/telemetry                 ║
║                                                                        ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
^[[20;149R
> cwebp-bin@5.1.0 postinstall /usr/src/app/client/node_modules/cwebp-bin
> node lib/install.js

  ⚠ spawn /usr/src/app/client/node_modules/cwebp-bin/vendor/cwebp ENOENT
  ⚠ cwebp pre-build test failed
  ℹ compiling from source
  ✖ Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c ./configure --disable-shared --prefix="/usr/src/app/client/node_modules/cwebp-bin/vendor" --bindir="/usr/src/app/client/node_modules/cwebp-bin/vendor"
configure: error: in `/usr/src/app/client/node_modules/cwebp-bin/480eb720-43ce-41c4-974d-409b7a015676':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details

checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
checking whether make supports nested variables... no
checking for style of include used by make... none
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no

    at /usr/src/app/client/node_modules/bin-build/node_modules/execa/index.js:231:11
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)

> mozjpeg@6.0.1 postinstall /usr/src/app/client/node_modules/mozjpeg
> node lib/install.js

  ⚠ spawn /usr/src/app/client/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor/cjpeg ENOENT
  ⚠ mozjpeg pre-build test failed
  ℹ compiling from source
  ✖ Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c autoreconf -fiv
/bin/sh: autoreconf: not found


    at /usr/src/app/client/node_modules/bin-build/node_modules/execa/index.js:231:11
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)

> pngquant-bin@5.0.2 postinstall /usr/src/app/client/node_modules/pngquant-bin
> node lib/install.js

  ✔ pngquant pre-build test passed successfully

> gatsby-cli@2.8.27 postinstall /usr/src/app/client/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/gatsby-cli
> node scripts/postinstall.js


> gatsby@2.19.7 postinstall /usr/src/app/client/node_modules/gatsby
> node scripts/postinstall.js

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

added 1991 packages from 980 contributors and audited 23093 packages in 48.538s

40 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

Removing intermediate container a927c5229081
 ---> 29563dd3fd59
Step 5/7 : COPY . .
 ---> 8d275e717a7f
Step 6/7 : EXPOSE 8000
 ---> Running in b1f9c944d0eb
Removing intermediate container b1f9c944d0eb
 ---> 77789e60189e
Step 7/7 : CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
 ---> Running in 4222ee128e48
Removing intermediate container 4222ee128e48
 ---> d64965213fff
Successfully built d64965213fff
Successfully tagged docker-gatsby-client:latest
WARNING: Image for service client was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Creating cwr_backend_1 ... done
Creating cwr_client_1  ... done
Attaching to cwr_backend_1, cwr_client_1
backend_1  | 
backend_1  | > backend@0.0.1 start /usr/src/app/backend
backend_1  | > nest start
backend_1  | 
client_1   | 
client_1   | > gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 start /usr/src/app/client
client_1   | > npm run develop
client_1   | 
client_1   | 
client_1   | > gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 develop /usr/src/app/client
client_1   | > gatsby develop
client_1   | 
client_1   | ╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
client_1   | ║                                                                        ║
client_1   | ║   Gatsby collects anonymous usage analytics                            ║
client_1   | ║   to help improve Gatsby for all users.                                ║
client_1   | ║                                                                        ║
client_1   | ║   If you'd like to opt-out, you can use `gatsby telemetry --disable`   ║
client_1   | ║   To learn more, checkout https://gatsby.dev/telemetry                 ║
client_1   | ║                                                                        ║
client_1   | ╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
^[[20;149Rclient_1   | success open and validate gatsby-configs - 0.023s
client_1   | 
client_1   |  ERROR
client_1   | 
client_1   | Error in "/usr/src/app/client/node_modules/gatsby-transformer-sharp/gatsby-node.js": 'linux-x64' binaries cannot be used on the 'linuxmusl-x64' platform. Please remove the 'node_modules/sharp/vendor' directory and run 'npm install'.
client_1   | 
client_1   | 
client_1   | 
client_1   |   Error: 'linux-x64' binaries cannot be used on the 'linuxmusl-x64' platform. Pl  ease remove the 'node_modules/sharp/vendor' directory and run 'npm install'.
client_1   |   
client_1   |   - libvips.js:67 Object.hasVendoredLibvips
client_1   |     [client]/[sharp]/lib/libvips.js:67:13
client_1   |   
client_1   |   - constructor.js:8 Object.<anonymous>
client_1   |     [client]/[sharp]/lib/constructor.js:8:22
client_1   |   
client_1   |   - v8-compile-cache.js:178 Module._compile
client_1   |     [client]/[v8-compile-cache]/v8-compile-cache.js:178:30
client_1   |   
client_1   |   - loader.js:991 Object.Module._extensions..js
client_1   |     internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10
client_1   |   
client_1   |   - loader.js:811 Module.load
client_1   |     internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32
client_1   |   
client_1   |   - loader.js:723 Function.Module._load
client_1   |     internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14
client_1   |   
client_1   |   - loader.js:848 Module.require
client_1   |     internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19
client_1   |   
client_1   |   - v8-compile-cache.js:159 require
client_1   |     [client]/[v8-compile-cache]/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20
client_1   |   
client_1   |   - index.js:3 Object.<anonymous>
client_1   |     [client]/[sharp]/lib/index.js:3:15
client_1   |   
client_1   |   - v8-compile-cache.js:178 Module._compile
client_1   |     [client]/[v8-compile-cache]/v8-compile-cache.js:178:30
client_1   |   
client_1   |   - loader.js:991 Object.Module._extensions..js
client_1   |     internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10
client_1   |   
client_1   |   - loader.js:811 Module.load
client_1   |     internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32
client_1   |   
client_1   |   - loader.js:723 Function.Module._load
client_1   |     internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14
client_1   |   
client_1   |   - loader.js:848 Module.require
client_1   |     internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19
client_1   |   
client_1   |   - v8-compile-cache.js:159 require
client_1   |     [client]/[v8-compile-cache]/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20
client_1   |   
client_1   |   - safe-sharp.js:127 Object.<anonymous>
client_1   |     [client]/[gatsby-plugin-sharp]/safe-sharp.js:127:11
client_1   |   
client_1   | 
client_1   | not finished load plugins - 0.192s
client_1   | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
client_1   | npm ERR! errno 1
client_1   | npm ERR! gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 develop: `gatsby develop`
client_1   | npm ERR! Exit status 1
client_1   | npm ERR! 
client_1   | npm ERR! Failed at the gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 develop script.
client_1   | npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
client_1   | 
client_1   | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
client_1   | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-02-08T23_01_53_782Z-debug.log
client_1   | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
client_1   | npm ERR! errno 1
client_1   | npm ERR! gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 start: `npm run develop`
client_1   | npm ERR! Exit status 1
client_1   | npm ERR! 
client_1   | npm ERR! Failed at the gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 start script.
client_1   | npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
client_1   | 
client_1   | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
client_1   | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-02-08T23_01_53_807Z-debug.log
cwr_client_1 exited with code 1
backend_1  | [Nest] 28   - 02/08/2020, 11:01:56 PM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
backend_1  | [Nest] 28   - 02/08/2020, 11:01:56 PM   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +15ms
backend_1  | [Nest] 28   - 02/08/2020, 11:01:56 PM   [RoutesResolver] AppController {/}: +4ms
backend_1  | [Nest] 28   - 02/08/2020, 11:01:56 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/, GET} route +2ms
backend_1  | [Nest] 28   - 02/08/2020, 11:01:56 PM   [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +2ms
```

I have removed the whole node_module directory and reran the `npm install` command in the directory to reinstall all pack and also rebuilt the docker image but I'm still getting the error.

Any recommendations on how to fix this issue is appreciated.

Comment: The `volumes:` tell Docker to use the `node_modules` tree from the very first time you ran the container; since you've told Docker that directory potentially contains important user data, it will never be updated.  I'd recommend deleting the `volumes:` blocks entirely and use the code that's actually being built in your image.

Comment: Do a refresh like @DavidMaze mentions. For some reason the error also mentions a `no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH`, this probably as to do with using the alpine version of the node image. Have you tried this with the regular node:12 image? it may narrow down your problem.

If its something with npm or your config it won't work with the regular image.
If its a dependency that the alpine version of the node docker image doesn't provide it should work with the non-alpine docker image.